# Is there a more efficient way to run multiple UPDATE sql statements

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-update

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to sql queries, and I only really have worked with the basic SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE statements. Now I need to update a lot of rows (50+) in a vertical table, and im running the statements like this:

```
UPDATE `postmeta` SET meta_value = 'John' WHERE `meta_key` = 'name' AND `post_id` = 29230;
UPDATE `postmeta` SET meta_value = 'Johnson' WHERE `meta_key` = 'last_name' AND `post_id` = 29230;
UPDATE `postmeta` SET meta_value = 'www.johnsonsdiner.com' WHERE `meta_key` = 'url' AND `post_id` = 29230;
UPDATE `postmeta` SET meta_value = 'john@johnson.com' WHERE `meta_key` = 'mail' AND `post_id` = 29230;
UPDATE `postmeta` SET meta_value = '12341234' WHERE `meta_key` = 'phone' AND `post_id` = 29230;
... + 45 more
```

Notice that the post_id is the same, while the meta_key differs.

is there a better way to run all these updates, that would have better performance for mySQL? would it make a difference to add a LIMIT 1 to each statement?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: My advice would be to step back to a proper 3NF normalised schema, then you could do the whole lot in _one_ update statement. This particular schema looks like those put together by those ORMs that give you flexibility of pseudo-schema updates without changing the _actual_ DB schema, at the cost of far more complex queries. In 3NF, there would be a table with _one_ row per post ID and it would contain name, last_name, etc, as columns.

Comment: @paxdiablo - I know. I would love it if I could change the schema, but thats not an option in this case unfortunately. so I gotta find a way around it without hitting performance too hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use only one `update` with a `case` statement for none common conditions also bring the common conditions to where clause:

```
UPDATE `postmeta`
        SET meta_value = case
             when `meta_key` = 'name' then 'John'
             when `meta_key` = 'last_name' then 'Johnson'
             when `meta_key` = 'url' then 'www.johnsonsdiner.com'
             when `meta_key` = 'mail' then 'john@johnson.com'
             when `meta_key` = 'phone' then '12341234' 
             .
             ...45 more
             .
             end
where `post_id` = 29230;
```

Comment: Would this improve performance compared to separate update statements? Im worried that it'll have to run all cases against all meta_keys in order to know if it needs to set it? any way to test the performance difference?

Comment: of course checking post_id one time has better performance than much times, also for every update command the db engine checks all rows for the condition (45 *  numberofrows) checks, but in one update with case statements it checks (numberofrows * (less than 45)) times because the condition maybe in first when in case statement

Comment: I was jus curious and tried it out. None of the `meta_key`'s have been updated. What is wrong in this Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c6ad/1

Comment: @trinimon yeah looks like you set the values as keys when inserting. changing that to name, last_name etc works fine :)

Comment: @farheg does that mean that as the table gets larger over time, the sql lookups gets worse and worse performance?

Comment: yes, but most of times specially if schema structure, indexes, query structure, etc be proper, and capacity of data is not too much (thera) it's not sensible

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhh ... stupid me :( I exchanged the columns - this was my plan: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d00ad/1 :D

Comment: This definitely was a solution to my question, though I'm gonna choose to serialize the data into a single field in this case instead. I know this is no considered good practice, but im my case I feel confident that it will simplify the whole process, and its not likely that there will ever be performed a search/replace on the this data. Thank you all!

Comment: It does look like it will compare each update with each existing row.  So, perhaps the INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE could be faster.

Comment: I thought also on "insert on duplicate key update" but it is slower even than batch updates specially here we have not inserts at all, we have only updates,  "insert on duplicate key update" is good for when we have inserts but update if exists. it checks whole table if a value not exists then inserts some values otherwise if exists then will update some values

Answer (score 0):

One other approach would be to use INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE if you know the primary key for each row you update.

So assuming (for illustration purposes) that `(post_id, meta_key)` is your primary key, the following query will solve your need:

```
INSERT INTO postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES (29230,'name','John'), (29230,'last_name','Johnson'),...
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE meta_value = VALUES(meta_value)
```

If the `(post_id, meta_key)` is not declared as a unique constraint, then you would need to first do a select to know primary key for rows you are updating, but be wary and consider possible race conditions that might apply in your situation.

Comment: "insert on duplicate update" is good when we have inserts and we want update some values if specific values exists. here in this scenario we have not insert at all so even batch updates (as came in the question) is much better than INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: fair point, if we don't know if a record exists, then insert is absolutely a no-go